# C#: Get Enum Name as String

Tags: c#, enums

Let's say I have this class:

```
public class SiteMapEntry  
{
    public static enum ChangeFrequency
    {
        Always,
        Hourly,
        Daily,
        Weekly,
        Monthly,
        Yearly,
        Never
    }
}
```

And this function:

```
public class FooBar(SiteMapEntry.ChangeFrequency changeFreq)
{

}
```

Which is called:

```
string foobarNever = FooBar(SiteMapEntry.ChangeFrequency.Never);
```

What do I need to do in the method `FooBar` to have the `string foobarNever == "never"`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

changeFreq.ToString() will give you a string representation of the enum value.

Comment: And to go in the other direction, `Enum.Parse(...)` is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

string foobarNever = "never" :)

Alternatively, why aren't you just doing:

```
if(FooBar(SiteMapEntry.ChangeFrequency.Never) == SiteMapEntry.ChangeFrequency.Never)
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of interacting with enums. For best practice, always compare an enum with the defined type:

```
if(changeFreq == ChangeFrequency.Never)
```

not

```
if(changeFreq.ToString() == "Never")
```

as it is more descriptive. If you need to convert a string value to the enum type, then use

```
try
{
    convertedValue = (ChangeFrequency)Enum.Parse(typeof(ChangeFrequency), stringValue);
}
catch
{
    convertedValue = ChangeFrequency.Always; // Whatever default you want
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Your_ENUM_List` in the code example with your ENUM and run this code.

```
string Result = "";

Type Enum_Name= typeof(  Your_ENUM_List  );

int Enum_Number = 0;

Result = Enum.ToObject(Enum_Name, Enum_Number).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may heard that **enum.toString()** has performance issue, so better to use **nameof(enum.x)**, e.g nameof(ChangeFrequency.Always) will return "Always"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BoE5Y6Xkm6w&t=51s